# How to correctly parse JSON with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

My goal is to get the top-most "browser_download_url" field  on this [JSON data](https://api.github.com/repos/s0uthwest/futurerestore/releases/latest) so I can use it to find the newest release of an application on Github.

I'm currently using Swift 4.2 with Alamofire to get the network data, and SwiftyJSON to parse the data.

---

I started off with a test so I can get the hang of it, using this [simple JSON data](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos) first.

This is my code

```
    Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let test = swiftyJsonVar[0]["title"].string {
                print(test)
```

Running the code would print `test` as being `delectus aut autem` which is correct from JSON data.

---

Though I attempt to use the code for my original goal, as follows

```
    Alamofire.request("https://api.github.com/repos/s0uthwest/futurerestore/releases/latest").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
          //  print(swiftyJsonVar)
            if let test = swiftyJsonVar[0]["assets"]["browser_download_url"].string {
                print(test)
```

Though running the code results in nothing. I'm certain it's an issue with the way I'm trying to get the `browser_download_url` so I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you use Swift 4.2? Then answer is: don’t use SwiftyJSON. Use **Codable** instead

Comment: I guess I was going to use SwiftyJSON as it made it look a lot easier. Though I will look into how to use the built-in feature of Codable.

Comment: actually, it’s much easier to use Codable

Comment: @HaMza What became of this? I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple with `Codable`.

1. Create a `struct`

   ```
   struct Item: Codable {
       let userId: Int
       let id: Int
       let title: String
       let completed: Bool
   }
   ```
2. In the Alamofire completion handler, you just decode it, like so:

   ```
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()

   do {
       // don't force unwrap in your project
       var yourStructs = try decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data!)
       print("yourStructs contains \(String(yourStructs.count)) items")
   } catch {
       print("kaboom!", error)
   }
   ```

Comment: Never, never, never print `error.localizedDescription` when catching `Decodable` errors. You get a quite meaningless generic error message. **Always** `print(error)` to get a precise information what went wrong.

Comment: @vadian Updated